# Is it possible to upgrade/downgrade from one Instance type to a completely different Instance type?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I know its possible to upgrade from one medium M3 Instance type to large M3.

But what about upgrade from medium M3 to Large R3? Is this possible?
(they are instance type)

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Answer (score 3):

There is a limitation as to changing instance sizes within EC2, this is to do with the virtualisation type (PV or HVM) the generation of VM (some of the older instance types such as t1.micro cannot be resized to newer instance types such as t2.micro).

As long as the instances are using the same virtualisation type then you can change the size between any of the current generation tiers.

See the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html#resize-limitations) on this for further information.

In summary, the answer to your question is **yes you should be able to upgrade** between the 2 instances you have specifically asked about.